# Let's Encrypt on Traefik with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, traefik, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install Traefik as an Ingress Controller for my self-installed Kubernetes cluster. For convenience I try to install the [helm chart of Traefik](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/traefik) and this works excellent without the acme part; this is my variables yml now:

```
externalIP: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: traefik-ui.example.com
ssl:
  enabled: true
  enforced: true
acme:
  enabled: true
  challengeType: http-01
  email: example@gmail.com
  staging: true
  persistence.enabled: true
  logging: true
```

Installed with:

```
helm install --name traefik --namespace kube-traefik --values traefik-variables.yml stable/traefik
```

But with `helm status traefik` I can see the `v1/PersistentVolumeClaim` named `traefik-acme` stays pending and the certificate is never assigned.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly recommended you use [`cert-manager`](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager) instead of the built-in ACME support in Traefik, at least at this time. It is much better at dealing with multiple copies of Traefik, which you probably want. Ingress-shim (which is a default part of cert-manager) will handle Traefik-backed Ingresses just fine.

Comment: Do you still recommend that in October 2018 or did the built-in ACME support mature to the point that you can recommend it.

Comment: The built-in ACME support isn't immature per se, the issue is that Traefik on K8s has no simple way to share the ACME data between multiple Traefik instances (which you usually want for HA). Cert-manager does not have this problem.

Comment: For future readers of this answer, this was brought up with Traefik development team on their slack and they said: "We (the Traefik team) recommend the opposite. we never recommended to use `cert-manager`" So it's up to the reader to choose which recommendation to heed.

Comment: Again, this isn't a question of opinion. Unless either 1) run another etcd cluster for use as a traefik K/V store or 2) use a ReadWriteMany PV backend, you cannot use Traefik's built-in ACME support with more than one replica running. If you are okay with being limited to a single replica, or meeting one of the two listed requirements, then you can use the internal support. Otherwise, use cert-manager. Or just use cert-manager.

Comment: @coderanger could you include some configuration code as an example??

Comment: There is no specific configuration required. cert-manager supports all Ingress controllers via the ingress-shim subsystem.

Comment: Is there any change in Traefik v2 ? ( acme.json over shared filesystem with locking support )